# Checkbox evenhandler for Checked Changed event dosen't trigger when checked state is modified

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, checkbox, triggers

The CheckBox dosen't trigger oncheckedchanged event:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="ccCritica" runat="server" 
                                style="z-index: 1; right: 15px; top: 100px; position: absolute" 
                                oncheckedchanged="ccCritica_CheckedChanged" />
```

.

```
protected void ccCritica_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(ccCritica.Checked == true)
    {
        ddSarcinaDep.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

I've tried with debug and it dosen't call the eventhandler.I'm using Visual Studio 2010 professional, and I'm Developing an ASP.NET Web application.Thanks

Comment: I can't see `AutoPostBack = "True"`.

Comment: Unless AutoPostBack is set to true, your event will not fire until another control (such as a button) forces a postback.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set `AutoPostBack="true"` in aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="ccCritica" runat="server" style="z-index: 1; right: 15px; top: 100px; position: absolute" AutoPostBack="true"
                            oncheckedchanged="ccCritica_CheckedChanged" />

    protected void ccCritica_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ccCritica.Checked == true)
        {

            ccCritica.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```